# How to insert HTML tags into WordPress date?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to place  tags around the month part of a date in Wordpress, but I can't work out how to do it.

I have tried the below, but this doesn't work.  Any ideas?

```
<?php date('j<b>M</b>', strtotime(the_date())); ?>
```

Comment: 1) You probably want to *output* your date 2) Please read the manual for **`date()`** and what the first parameter takes

Comment: It still doesn't work if I echo it out.

Comment: what format is the `the_date()` ??

Comment: It's...`Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/xUfpVH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the format as an argument to `the_date()`:

```
<?php the_date("j<b>M</b>"); ?>
```

The reference is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date